# Error while attempting to install opencv-python using pip on Windows 10

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I have been trying to install opencv for Python 3.8.0 on fresh install of Windows 10. Here is the command I ran:

`C:\Windows\system32>py -m pip install opencv-python`

However, I was met with this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

I have tried:

- Running the command prompt as admin
- Upgrading pip using `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`
- Checking to make sure I was able to install other libraries with pip. (I tried [discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/) and [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), all worked)

Comment: Your python version?

Comment: Python Version 3.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opencv-python` is a collection of pre-built `whl` files, as you can see in the project description on the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python):

> OpenCV on Wheels
>
> Unofficial pre-built OpenCV packages for Python.

And is the case for many modules currently, there are no whl files for python 3.8 in that project.

So simply install a different python version and try again with

```
pip install opencv-python
```

or

download the whl for python 3.8 from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) and then do

```
pip install opencv_python‑4.1.2‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
```